# what will be the arguments for this code

Tags: c

I have the following code and I would like to know 2 things
What will be first in this expression (*++argv) and what this expression will mean after with the [0]?
Lets say the program named "program" what example of arguments in command line will not lead to the default but will lead to the other two or one cases?
2)And what example of arguments in command line will lead to default?
3)and an example that will not lead to switch case or in the default case..

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])  
{  
    int c, except = 0, number = 0; 
    while ((--argc) > 0 && (*++argv)[0] == '-')  
        while (c = *++(argv[0]))  
            switch (c) {  
            case 'x':  
                except = 1;  
                break;  
            case 'n':  
                number = 1;  
                break;  
            default:  
                printf(" illegal option %c\n", c);  
                exit(-1); 
                break;  
            }  
   ..more code
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You can Debug your code and see everything u need

Comment: I am using online compilers ..It is just a code that have been given in an exam and I would like to know the above questions..

Comment: There are freely available compilers and IDEs for C. Best to get one of these and look at the code yourself.

Comment: install linux download gcc...profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) arguments that will switch *x* case is **-x** / for *n* it's **-n**

2) arguments that will switch *default* are '**-**' followed by every char except **x** and **n** (like **-a** or **-P**)

3) arguments that will not switch are those that doesn't begin with '**-**'

Comment: What c will do first in this expression (*++argv) (increment or pointer) ?

Comment: and the two whiles can you explain to me?\

Comment: It will first increment, and then point at the incremented value

Comment: The first while says: "While there is remaining arguments (--argc) and while the first char of the next argv is '-'". The second says "if there is a char after '-' and stores it in 'c'"

Comment: i still didn't got the second while '        while (c = *++(argv[0]))  ' it doesn't increments the argv[0] ?

Comment: In "-foo", c value will be 'f' because || argv[0]: points to "-foo" || *argv[0]: points to "-" || *++argv[0]: points to "f".